# UDP hole punching for an already existent application

Tags: udp, hole-punching

I'm attempting to use YAWCam on my university network. I am using it as an mjpg streamer that another application behind another network needs to access. Unfortunately, there is no way to port forward on my university network. enter [udp-hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching). I thought this was fantastic when I learned of it, but quickly realized that, unless I could figure out how to actually modify this program (which is not open source) I would not be able to make UDP hole punching work conventionally.

My question is, is there a way to hole punch without changing the original program? possibly by sending packets from the same port yawcam uses to punch the hole, and then let regular requests refresh it? I'm a bit new to netcode so Im not entirely sure what the "correct" method is for this.

Comment: May as well try the simplist method first. UPNP port mapping. https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper chances are the university has it blocked.

Comment: How would I use the portmapping tool? I don't have actual access to any of the routers. That was the original problem. In fact, YAWCam works at my home simply because my home router has upnp enabled. No port forwarding needed. Simply running YAWCam (and assuming that upnp is enabled on their network) doesnt work. (requests to the IP and port dont go through.) This was why I wanted to try writing something that would "punch the hole for" YAWCam, so it could work more like skype (which works on my unis network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. Two different programs can't bind to same port. The purpose of port numbers is to identify which running application instance to route the traffic to. if two applications were to each bind two sockets to the same port number, that routing becomes impossible.